# JavaScript Audio looping with autoplay features

Tags: javascript

hey friends,

I am making a game based on html5 and JS, i want to play a audio clip of 8 seconds in background in loop but when I add audio in HTML code by using :

```
<audio src="audio.mp3" autoplay loop></loop>
```

but still it plays audio for once.

can anybody tell me how to do this??

Comment: here's an article about looping-possibilities http://forestmist.org/blog/html5-audio-loops/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to check these posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747526/why-wont-my-html5-audio-loop) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273552/html-5-audio-looping) because some browsers have issues with loop attribute so you have to do it manually.